# Diff-in-Diff Model

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference

I am working with a DID model, I have the Y column, the treatment column with dummies, the time period column with dummies and the interaction. How do I add Year-fixed effect, State-Fixed effect and time trend? Also is this the correct data set up?
Id greatly appreciate any help

[image: data set]

Comment: Could you show your data structure so others can see what you mean?

Comment: Sure I will edit the original post